# ibm cloud private 3.2.1 helm issue

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I am getting the following message while installing ICP on Ubuntu.
I searched for helm-api-3.1.0.tgz and that the file exists.
Any idea what would cause this?

```
TASK [addon : Installing helm-api chart]
FAILED - RETRYING: Installing helm-api chart (5 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Installing helm-api chart (4 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Installing helm-api chart (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Installing helm-api chart (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Installing helm-api chart (1 retries left).
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=true 
  attempts: 5
  cmd: |-
filename="/addon/helm-api-3.1.0.tgz"
 if [[ -d "/addon/helm-api-3.1.0.tgz" ]]; then
 filename=$(ls /addon/helm-api-3.1.0.tgz/*.tgz | tail -1)
 fi
 ret=0
 if helm status --tls helm-api &>/dev/null && helm status --tls helm-api | grep -q 'STATUS: FAILED'; then
 rev=$(helm list --tls helm-api | awk '{if($1 == "helm-api"){print $2;exit}}')
 if [[ "$rev" == "1" ]]; then
 helm delete --tls --purge --timeout=600 helm-api
 ret=$?
 sleep 5
 fi
 fi
 if ! helm status --tls helm-api &>/dev/null; then
 helm upgrade --tls --install --force --timeout=600 --namespace=kube-system -f .addon/helm-api/values.yaml helm-api $filename
 ret=$?
 fi
 if [[ $ret -ne 0 ]]; then
 tiller_pod=$(kubectl -n kube-system get pods -l app=helm,name=tiller -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
 kubectl -n kube-system logs $tiller_pod &> /installer/cluster/logs/$tiller_pod
 echo "============================================================"
 echo "Tiller log can be found under cluster/logs/$tiller_pod"
 echo "============================================================"
 fi
 exit $ret
```

> delta: '0:00:01.819853'   end: '2018-11-12 16:21:59.248602'   msg:
>   non-zero return code   rc: 1   start: '2018-11-12 16:21:57.428749'
>   stderr: 'Error: secrets "rudder-secret" already exists'
>   stderr_lines:    stdout: |-
>       Release "helm-api" does not exist. Installing it now.
>       ============================================================
>       Tiller log can be found under cluster/logs/tiller-deploy-57b467b45b-c6xqg
>       ============================================================   stdout_lines:

Comment: output are shown in blockquote

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the problem is this:

> 'Error: secrets "rudder-secret" already exists'

I'm not positive what might cause it, but my first thought would be a previously failed installation left something behind. So your best bet might be to clean the machine from previous installations, and start over. [This page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_3.1.0/installing/uninstall_ce.html) might help with cleaning things up.

If you can use `kubectl`, you might be able to run these commands to manually remove the secrets:

`kubectl delete secrets/helmapi-secret --namespace kube-system
kubectl delete secrets/rudder-secret --namespace kube-system`

Then you might be able to resume or restart the installation. I don't think this would work as well as uninstalling, cleaning up, and starting over.